# Nothing happens when addSubview image

Tags: objective-c

Here is the code:

```
CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
[myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Angry0.png"]];
[mainView addSubview:myImage];
```

`Angry0.png` is in my Resources folder. No image is display on simulator.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the code and check to see if mainView isn't null.. Also try setting myImage's backgroundColor to red or something to see if it's actually being added to mainView or not... Also, whats mainView's frame? Has that got a superview?

Comment: Oups, just replace mainView by imageView. In fact, imageView is in ScrollView, that ScrollView is in contentView and that contentView is in mainView.

Comment: All my views, except mainView has 0x00000000 as adress

Comment: Are you setting the ScrollViews contentSize property? Height needs to be at least 400 + (line*length) + 100

Comment: That means you are not initializing them... I'll post an answer up with some help

Comment: Yes I'm setting contentSize property. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right... You need to initalize all your views...

If I'm right your view hierarchy is this:

```
-mainView
     -contentView
         -scrollView
              -imageView
```

So somewhere when you load mainView you also need to initalize all the child views...

For example:

```
...
//put this where you call mainView = [[UIView alloc] init...

contentView = [[UIView alloc] init...
//config the contentView

scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init...
//config the scrollView

....
```

Now, providing that you correctly set your views frames and initialized them they shouldn't be null...

You can check by calling:

```
if (!scrollView) {
    NSLog(@"scrollView is null :(");
}
```

Then you should be able to call your existing code and all should be good

Comment: Yes it's my hierarchy. But there's nowhere in my code something like mainView = [[UIView alloc]... However, I can easily add my image in mainView without alloc method...

Can be the problem the declaration of my whew ? For example:

`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mainView;`
`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;`
`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;`
`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *imageView;`

Comment: Ann didnt realise you was using xbib... In the xbib editor have you linked the other views and made sure they are added to the parent view (Ie: scrollView is in contentView)

Comment: Yes Im using Storyboard for all my view. And I link the view with their variable in ViewController.h

Comment: Ahh sorry, I haven't even used storyboards before so maybe someone else may be able to help better... Good luck